# Are Faber-Castell pencils meant to be oily?

Tags: pencils, material-identification

I purchased a pack of Faber-Castell "Grip 2001" graphite pencils (see image.below).
I've bought other Faber-Castell grip pencils before, but not these specific ones. I've used their "Colour Grip" and "Art Grip Aquarelle", which didn't feel oily, but the "Grip 2001" pencil's grip feels oily.

I’m trying to figure out if they’re meant to be like that or not: does any know?

[image: photo depicting the Art Grip Aquarelle, Colour Grip, and Grip 2001 pencils lying on a wooden surface]

Comment: Just to verify that I'm reading the question right, are you referring to the lead seeming oily as you use it, or the outside of the wooden part feeling oily when you hold it? If it's the outside, I can't imagine that they would intentionally be made that way. In that case, my guess would be either something oily got on it, or a problem with the paint finish. You could try wiping the outside with a paper towel dampened with a little soapy water to see if that removes the oiliness. Soapy water shouldn't affect the paint or artwork on the outside.

Comment: I have a Grip 2001 pencil as well and never experienced something like that, so my guess is that it's a remnant of the production process of the grip zone.

Comment: @fixer1234 I’m referring to the out side, specifically the little grip dots. I did try wiping it down with a dry part of my T-shirt so I’ll have to give you’re idea a go.

Comment: @Joachim Ok, thank you.

Comment: Morgan, post back with how that works out.  If it doesn't work, that will open it up to other ideas. If that works, consider posting an answer. There are likely other people with the same experience, and sharing solutions is what the site is about.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 Ok, I just gave it a go, and at first I did think it helped, but after drying the pencil and my hands off properly It still feels oily unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not familiar with those pencils.  Can I assume from the name and discussion that the dots are slightly raised bumps of something rubbery? Can you tell whether it's the bumps or the paint (or both) that have the oily feel?

Comment: I had similar problems with grip pencils after storing them for a prolonged time. At some point the plasticiser in the rubbery material seem to disintegrate. Do the dots feel sticky?

Comment: If the problem is what @samcarter_prepared_for_xmas posted, here's something else to try.  Dampen a paper towel with rubbing alcohol and go over the grip area.  There's a chance it could strip off some of the paint, but it usually gets rid of that kind of residue. Let it dry completely (make sure the paint isn't sticky or soft), then dry-wipe it with a paper towel to remove any dry residue. There's always a chance some of the rubber dots could come off, in which case, you'll have the "non-grip" version of the pencil.  :-)

Comment: @samcarter_prepared_for_xmas Hm, ok

Comment: Morgan, any update on this?

Comment: @samcarter_prepared_for_xmas I’m so sorry for not updating this! I had a small party that day and I’m no longer exactly sure where I put the pencils which is why I haven’t updated this

Answer (score 1):

The grip dots are likely made of thermoplastic elastomer, or TPE, as this material often seems to be used for grips of handheld tools. This material can get oily if it comes into contact with oils or solvents, or when exposed to high temperatures .

As [mentioned in the comments](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/11034/are-faber-castell-pencils-meant-to-be-oily#comment13442_11034) (that is, on one account), this oiliness is not standard for the Faber-Castell Grip 2001.

You might be able to remove it, as suggested by user *fixer1234*, with some water and [mild detergent](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/11034/are-faber-castell-pencils-meant-to-be-oily#comment13441_11034), or with some [rubbing alcohol](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/11034/are-faber-castell-pencils-meant-to-be-oily#comment13456_11034).
Using talcum powder or cornstarch you might be able to (temporarily) lessen the oiliness.

The following [comment](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/39972202) from a forum on digital cameras might shed some more light as well:

> The "rubber" pad on the camera bottom is likely made from TPE - thermoplastic elastomer. Basically, it is a mixture of rubber and plastic that can be molded by thermoplastic injection molding machines. Google "Santoprene" for product information.
>
> Once of the things that occur with TPE is oil migration. Rubber contains oil and it will slowly migrate to the outer surface. This process occurs so slowly that it is not noticed unless you have something like a metal plate covering the TPE for an extended period, and/or subjected to heat.
>
> Wipe it clean. It is normal, and no big deal.